# Seperate keybindings for return, arrow-up, etc.?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, readline

I don't understand why <kbd>return</kbd> doesn't have it's own key when working with the *readline* of *bash*.

Using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> is the same as using <kbd>return</kbd>.

**How to create two separate keybindings, one for <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and another function for <kbd>return</kbd>?**

*The same applies to arrow-up/-down etc. . Printing them quoted shows that they are not a seperate key, but a key sequence, so I can not use that sequence for another function.*

Comment: What's the question here exactly? Can you rebind a specific key? Can you set a single character/byte for each individual key? Something else?

Comment: Edited the question, I want two different keybindings. `return` is needed for accept-line, but ⌃+m ist wasted in that way.

Comment: You can map `return` to produce anything you want but `^M` *is* carriage return and things are going to expect that. You would have to change the terminfo entry to fix that (and hope everything consults that correctly). I think. What "wasting" of `ctrl+m` are you worried about here? What would you want to use it for instead?

Comment: But my `return` key is producing `⌃M`, since I want to maintain that function to any other app on the system and keep my modified US-Layout. Only Terminal has that strange behavior.

Comment: "Only Terminal has that strange behaviour" ¿What strange behaviour?

Comment: Using Control+m and return for the same thing.

Comment: @ViktorLexington: Ah, I see what you mean.  It's part of vt100 emulation, so any terminal emulator would exhibit that behaviour. A GUI doesn't have that constraint.

Comment: It is not possible? pls as an answer.

Comment: What other application are you intending to use `return` for in your terminal if you could manage to "fix" this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed that, you would find it cumbersome to use any terminal application, because *all* of the POSIX-like systems use "newline" for ending lines.  An ASCII carriage return `^M` is normally translated into a *newline* (which happens to be encoded as ASCII line-feed `^J`).  If you run `stty -a` on your terminal you may notice something like this:

```
~ (4) stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 40 rows; 80 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

The `icrnl` says that carriage-return is mapped to newline.  So... if you break your `return` key, you could type *control/M* or *control/J* every time you want a newline.  Most people prefer just pressing one key for that purpose.